# How to assign a template to a campaign in MailChimp API v3.0?

Tags: javascript, python, web-services, mailchimp

I am currently working with the MailChimp API v3.0. My goal is to make the user manage his mailchimp account inside his own enviroment.
For now, I can crate list of contacts and the campaigns. My problem is that I can't assign a template to the campaign. Looking into the docs http://developer.mailchimp.com/documentation/mailchimp/reference/overview/, the create method for the campaign don't accept the template_id parameter. That way, the user can't send the emails, because he needs to go to the mailchimp website to assing the template before sending the emails.
Is there any way to do this, or the API simply doesn't support it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think, in v3, you would assign the `template_id` on the campaign's `content` sub-resource, as described [in the documentation](http://developer.mailchimp.com/documentation/mailchimp/reference/campaigns/content/#edit-put_campaigns_campaign_id_content).